# AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'File'

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I wanted to create a very basic site which allows to upload the images.I found the manual, however I wanted to make it slightly different. Here's my code:

```
###main.py

import os
from forms import UploadForm
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, redirect, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'string'

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and allowed_file(form.presentation.File.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(form.presentation.file.filename)

        print filename
        form.presentation.File.save(os.path.join('C:\Users\user\Desktop\New', filename))
    return redirect(url_for('/'))

    filename = None
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form, filename=filename)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

### forms.py   

from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import FileField, validators, ValidationError, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class UploadForm(Form):
  presentation = FileField('Upload Image here', validators=[InputRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField("Send")


### upload.html
   {% for message in form.presentation.errors %}
     <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
   <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ form.presentation.label }}
     {{ form.presentation }}
     {{ form.csrf_token }}
     {{ form.submit}}
   </form>
```

On executing I get an error: AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'File'
I've searched the whole day, but I cannot find the answer what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wtforms doc FileField does not have File attribute that's right.

Here is the doc example:

```
class UploadForm(Form):
    image        = FileField(u'Image File', [validators.regexp(u'^[^/\\]\.jpg$')])
    description  = TextAreaField(u'Image Description')

    def validate_image(form, field):
        if field.data:
            field.data = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9_.-]', '_', field.data)

def upload(request):
    form = UploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.image.data:
        image_data = request.FILES[form.image.name].read()
        open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, form.image.data), 'w').write(image_data)
```

As you can see the file is read from `request.FILE` not from the `FileField`. The `FileField` only has the attributes `name` and `data`.

Comment: [Post](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html?highlight=data) shows it reads from FileField:filename = secure_filename(form.photo.data.filename)
        form.photo.data.save('uploads/' + filename)

Comment: `image_data = request.FILES[form.image.name].read()` didn't work with **FILES** in capital letters but small letters **files**